# How to pause audio onclick right now its stop the audio and start from beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, audio, html5-canvas

Guys please help me in my project , first let me tell you the flow of my site , there are 4 deers each one contain a unique voice , when i click any each of them audio file play track and deer start animate , and when i click it again audio stopped and also animation is stop . Now if i again click on deer the audio starts from beginning . What i am trying to do is instead start from beginning the audio start where i stopped in other words I want to pause or mute the audio so when i click it again it start from where i stopped . Following is my site link , please do let me know if you want other info regarding this proj .
[My Project Link](http://uwebsolutions.co.uk/dev/ws/reindeer/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function $extend(e, t) {
    function a() {}
    a.prototype = e;
    var i, n = new a;
    for (i in t) n[i] = t[i];
    return n
}


function $bind(e, t) {
    var a = function() {
        return a.method.apply(a.scope, arguments)
    };
    return a.scope = e, a.method = t, a
}
var Horse = function(e) {
    this._play = !1, this._index = e;
    var t = createjs.SoundJS.getCapability("mp3") ? ".mp3" : ".ogg";
    this._sound = "r/" + this._index + t, t = Horse._sizes[e], 
    e = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        images: ["r/" + e + ".png"],
        frames: {
            width: t.w,
            height: t.h
        },
        animations: {
            sing: [0, Horse._totalFrames[e] - 1]
        }
    }), createjs.BitmapAnimation.call(this, e), console.log(e.getNumFrames("sing")), this.gotoAndStop(0), this.onClick = $bind(this, this.clickHandler)
};
Horse.__super__ = createjs.BitmapAnimation, Horse.prototype = $extend(createjs.BitmapAnimation.prototype, {
    clickHandler: function() {
        (this._play = !this._play) ? (this.gotoAndPlay("sing"), createjs.SoundJS.play(this._sound, createjs.SoundJS.INTERRUPT_NONE, -1, 0, 0)) : (this.gotoAndStop(0), createjs.SoundJS.stop(this._sound))
    }
});

var Main = function() {
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(12);
    var e = document.getElementById("canv");
    this._stage = new createjs.Stage(e);
    var t = new createjs.Bitmap("r/bg.jpg");
    this._stage.addChild(t), 
    t = new Horse(0), 
    t.x = 2, t.y = 45, 
    this._stage.addChild(t), 
    t = new Horse(1), 
    t.x = 150, t.y = 45, 
    this._stage.addChild(t), 
    t = new Horse(2), 
    t.x = 270, t.y = 45, 
    this._stage.addChild(t), 
    t = new Horse(3), 
    t.x = 395, 
    t.y = 45, 
    this._stage.addChild(t), 
    t = e.width / 550, 
    e = e.height / 300, 
    t > e ? t = e : e = t,
    this._stage.scaleX = t, 
    this._stage.scaleY = e, 
    this._stage.update(), 
    createjs.Ticker.addListener($bind(this, this.tickerHandler))
};
Main.main = function() {
    var e = new createjs.PreloadJS;
    e.installPlugin(createjs.SoundJS), e.onComplete = Main.loaderCompleteHandler, e.loadFile("r/bg.jpg"), createjs.SoundJS.checkPlugin(!0);
    for (var t = createjs.SoundJS.getCapability("mp3") ? ".mp3" : ".ogg", a = 0; 4 > a;) {
        var i = a++;
        e.loadFile("r/" + i + t), e.loadFile("r/" + i + ".png")
    }
}, Main.loaderCompleteHandler = function() {
    new Main
}, Main.prototype = {
    tickerHandler: function() {
        this._stage.update()
    }
};
var $_;
Horse._totalFrames = [8, 8, 8, 8], Horse._sizes = [{
    w: 152,
    h: 257
}, {
    w: 152,
    h: 257
}, {
    w: 152,
    h: 257
}, {
    w: 152,
    h: 257
}], Main.main();</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some code? The part where javascript stop the audio onClick...

Comment: I just updated description and share script which i am using .

Comment: Instead of `createjs.SoundJS.stop(this._sound)` use `createjs.SoundJS.pause(this._sound)` in the `clickHandler`

Comment: after using pause now when i stopped the audio i wont be able to play it again :(